# sed script with backslashes works in console or standalone script but not a Vagrantfile

Tags: bash, vagrant

I have this line:

```
sed -i 's/^\$cfg\['\''Servers'\''\]\[\$i\]\['\''AllowNoPassword'\''\] = .*/\$cfg\['\''Servers'\''\]\[\$i\]\['\''AllowNoPassword'\''\] = true;/' config.inc.php
```

Really simple line for editing my PHPMyAdmin `config.inc.php` `AllowNoPassword` to `true` (this is a dev environment of course).

It works perfectly in console but in a script file using vagrant it simply does not.

I do believe it is to do with the `'` but I cannot understand what the difference is.

What is going on here and how to solve it?

#### Edit

Here is a complete example, minus a few bits of logic to simplify it and remove some private details etc:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 4343, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

    add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

    apt-get update > /dev/null

    yes | apt-get install zip

    yes | apt-get install php7.1-fpm \
    php7.1-curl \
    php7.1-gd \
    php7.1-mysql \
    php7.1-mbstring \
    php7.1-xml \
    php7.1-mcrypt \
    php7.1-soap \
    php7.1-dev

    # Set the right user for PHP7 ("ubuntu" user)
    sed -i -e "s/www-data/ubuntu/g" /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

    # Fix error reporting so it is consistent with live server
    sed -i 's/^error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL/' /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
    sed -i 's/^error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL/' /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini

    yes | apt-get install php-pear
    pecl install xdebug

    # Add xdebug to PHP runtime
    echo 'zend_extension=xdebug.so' >> /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
    echo 'zend_extension=xdebug.so' >> /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini

    service php7.1-fpm restart

    debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root'
    debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root'
    yes | apt-get -y install mysql-server
    mysqladmin -u root -p'root' password ''
  SHELL

  $script = <<-SCRIPT
    cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php
    sed -i 's/^\$cfg\['\''Servers'\''\]\[\$i\]\['\''AllowNoPassword'\''\] = .*/\$cfg\['\''Servers'\''\]\[\$i\]\['\''AllowNoPassword'\''\] = true;/' config.inc.php
  SCRIPT
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script, privileged: false
  #config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
end
```

Comment: I'd suggest -- **strongly** suggest -- using tools that don't require that kind of impossible-to-debug eyesore. See `gsub_literal` from [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021).

Comment: Per [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/), single quote need to be changed to double quote: `sed -i "s/^\$cfg\['\''Servers'\''\]\[\$i\]\['\''AllowNoPassword'\''\] = .*/\$cfg\['\''Servers'\''\]\[\$i\]\['\''AllowNoPassword'\''\] = true;/" config.inc.php`

Comment: @Arash, the guidance from shellcheck is wrong in this case. The `$`s are *intentionally* literal. ("Expressions don't expand in single quotes" is the warning, but nothing is *intended* to expand).

Comment: @Sammaye, the details of *how* this is invoked from Vagrant matter immensely. Please try to provide a [mcve] -- see https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/d85b8355dc84ba3dacb777003e96aa68 for an attempt that *doesn't* create the problem (and thus shows the code working perfectly even via a script).

Comment: Ok,I will remove a lot and get a base example

Comment: There is a lot of processing in the script and I use sed many times but this is the only line that doesn't work

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok, try that. I kept some logic to show you how I have used sed in other places etc

Comment: I wonder if this could be the way vagrant reads it into ruby first... hmm

Comment: I'd suggest using `set -x`. If you can capture stderr, you can get the *real* command line that Vagrant is running. (Though this should indeed be reproducible now). Or you can just directly copy in a real, literal script rather than including it in your Vagrantfile.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true, if it gets too annoying I will include it as a separate bash script, though I want to make this script portable and the more files the less portable :(

Comment: Depends on the meaning of "portable". In the "componentized, reusable in other environments" sense of the word, it strikes me that separating components (not to be written in highly localized syntax -- such as, in this case, escaping only meaningful in the context of shell embedded in a Ruby heredoc) *improves* portability.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy my definition of portable here is "easy to copy and not prone to human error". But if I have to copy around two or three files then: meh, that's life

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an *escaped* heredoc:

```
  $script = <<-'SCRIPT'
    cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php
    sed -i 's/^\$cfg\['\''Servers'\''\]\[\$i\]\['\''AllowNoPassword'\''\] = .*/\$cfg\['\''Servers'\''\]\[\$i\]\['\''AllowNoPassword'\''\] = true;/' config.inc.php
  SCRIPT
```

The quotes around `SCRIPT` indicate to the Ruby interpreter that all contents should be literal -- taken *precisely* as given rather than prone to expansions. (Such quotes have the same meaning in shell heredocs as well).

Comment: You, sir, are a legend